# Find all references of a symbol that is attributed with some special attribute

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to craft an analyzer that will throw a message (severity = info) for every occurence of some attributed member in code. That mimicks the behaviour of `[Obsolete(...)]` but throws only a message instead.

The attribute definition would be something like

```
public class ThrowsMessageAttribute : Attribute
{
  // ...
}
```

The member I want to throw a message for would then be attributed with it:

```
public class Foo
{
  [ThrowsMessage]
  public void Bar() { }
}
```

For each `Bar()` I use in my code, I would now get an entry in the message tab of the error list.

My starting point is an empty DiagnosticAnalyzer class:

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
internal class MyDiagnosticAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
  private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Descriptor =
    new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Info, true, Description, HelpLink);

  public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics { get; } = ImmutableArray.Create(Descriptor);

  public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
  {
    // how to go on from here?
  }
}
```

Having an `AnalysisContext` how do I move on? What is the logic that I need to implement in ordner to find all references of symbols which are attributed in a distinguished way?

Maybe I am completely on the wrong track and solving this problem should not be done via an analyzer. What other options are available?

**EDIT**

Based on the suggestion of @Tamás I got it working almost with the following code:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
  context.RegisterSemanticModelAction(Analyze);
}

private static void Analyze(SemanticModelAnalysisContext context)
{
  var semanticModel = context.SemanticModel;
  var step2 = GetSymbolsOfAttributedMethods(semanticModel, "ThrowsMessage");
  Step3(context, list2, semanticModel);
}

private static List<ISymbol> GetSymbolsOfAttributedMethods(SemanticModel semanticModel, string attributeName)
{
  var methodDeclarations = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
  var symbolList = new List<ISymbol>();

  foreach (var declaration in methodDeclarations)
  {
    foreach (var attributeList in declaration.AttributeLists)
    {
      if (attributeList.Attributes.Any(a => (a.Name as IdentifierNameSyntax)?.Identifier.Text == attributeName))
      {
        symbolList.Add(semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(declaration));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return symbolList;
}

private static void Step3(SemanticModelAnalysisContext context, List<ISymbol> attributedSymbols, SemanticModel semanticModel)
{
  var invocationExpressions = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<InvocationExpressionSyntax>();

  foreach (var invocation in invocationExpressions)
  {
    var symbol = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol;

    if (attributedSymbols.Contains(symbol))
    {
      var l = Location.Create(context.SemanticModel.SyntaxTree, invocation.FullSpan);
      context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, l));
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected but the location for which I am reporting the diagnostic is not yet quite right, because it is not only the invocation but also the trailing whitespace. Why is that?

Comment: Do you have warnings as errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the route I would take:

1. Register a `SemanticModelAction` with `context.RegisterSemanticModelAction`
2. Find the `MethodDeclaration` of methods with your special attribute and get the method's symbol. This would look something like this:

   ```
   private List<ISymbol> GetSymbolsOfAttributedMethods(string attributeName)
   {
       var methodDeclarations = semanticModel.SyntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
       var symbolList = new List<ISymbol>();

       foreach (var declaration in methodDeclarations)
       {
           foreach (var attributeList in declaration.AttributeLists)
           {
               if (attributeList.Attributes.Any(a => (a.Name as IdentifierNameSyntax)?.Identifier.Text == attributeName))
               {
                   symbolList.Add(semanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(declaration));
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
       return symbolList;
   }
   ```

   `semanticModel` can be aquired from the context of the action you registered.
3. Go through all `InvocationExpression`s (getting them in a similar fashion as we did with the `methodDeclarations`, load their symbol (make sure you use `GetSymbolInfo(invocation).Symbol` here and not `GetDeclaredSymbol` as we did earlier).
4. Compare the symbols from step 3 to the symbols from step 2, and `ReportDiagnostic` if the invocation's symbol is among the ones with the special attribute.

**EDIT**

Regarding your edit, it is because you are using [`FullSpan`](http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/72A62CA7.htm).

> The absolute span of this node in characters, including its leading and trailing trivia.

Either use [`Span`](http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/B10CEACE.htm) or use [`invocation.GetLocation()`](http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/45AF643F.htm) and forget about creating the `Location` object altogether.

The [Roslyn reference](http://www.coderesx.com/roslyn/html/Welcome.htm) is pretty thorough so it's usually a good place to look. And don't forget the [Syntax Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK), the other tool that can make your life a 100 times easier.

Comment: You got me on the right track. Your off the top of the head suggestion was spotless. See my edit for a little follow-up question.